# What is the HTTP URL to be given in Cloud scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm very new to Google Cloud Platform. I'm trying to schedule a job using Cloud scheduler where the job has to run which will pick a script called "pipleline.py" in my dataflow console

I'm unable to understand the link, or understanding what should the URL be when creating a cloud scheduler job. Please help me how to go about it

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent example [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/schedule-dataflow-jobs-with-cloud-scheduler) to schedule Dataflow jobs with Cloud Scheduler. It uses Terraform to create the Cloud Scheduler resource as you can see here:

```
http_target {
    http_method = "POST"
    uri = "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/${var.project_id}/locations/${var.region}/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://${var.bucket}/templates/dataflow-demo-template"
    ...
}
```

If you are not familiar with Terraform, you could just use the gcloud SDK to accomplish the same thing:

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs create http job_name \
  --schedule='every day' \
  --uri="https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$REGION/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/templates/dataflow-demo-template" \
  --message-body-from-file="dataflow_message_body.json" \
  --oauth-service-account-email=$DATAFLOW_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

The `dataflow_message_body.json` contains a json similar to:

```
{
  "jobName": "dataflow_job_name",
  "parameters": {
    "inputFilePattern": "gs://$BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/input.txt",
    "outputDirectory": "gs://$BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/output.txt.gz",
    "outputFailureFile": "gs://$BUCKET_NAME/dataflow/failure",
    "compression": "GZIP"
  },
  "gcsPath": "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Bulk_Compress_GCS_Files"
}
```

And if you want to do this in the console, just go to your project and then create a new Cloud Scheduler, which has the same fields as described above.

If you want to know how Google-provided templates look like, you could take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates). When you want to know how to create your own templates and the format they should have, take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#python_1). When starting a Dataflow job, you always refer to a location in a bucket, whether it is the Google-provided `gs://dataflow-templates` bucket or your own bucket.

Comment: Yes Thank you, I came across this link. And yes would want to do from Cloud Scheduler Console. But my question is, what should the parameter's for each variable defined above. For example, what should be the URL/URI and what should I refer and where for the URL in my project?

Comment: Create a bucket in your project and place a dataflow template in that bucket. Refer to that template in the above gcsPath query parameter in the uri.

Comment: I already have a script in Dataflow which is (Pipeline.py - The main script ; Bigquery script and JSON properties script) So should I copy all of them a bucket and use that link? I'm sorry I'm very new to this, hence finding it difficult to connect the dots.

Comment: I updated the question, see the last paragraph. It contains sources of pre-build and custom Dataflow templates, so you know how they should look like when placing them in a bucket. If you are totally new to this, I would recommend starting by running the word count example.